# Disable Auto Selecting the First Item in RadListControl When the WinForm is Loaded

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

I'm working with C# `Windows Forms` and Telerik UI.
I have `RadListControl` in my form. List data is bound in the constructor.

When the form is loaded the first item of the RadListControl is selected automatically.

In this case the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of the RadListControl is fired.

I have used `SelectedIndexChanged` event for specific process.

How to disable this first item selection when form is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

After initial loading of the `RadListControl` (if `DataSource` property is set) then the first item in the collection is selected and its  normal `behaviour` in `RadListControl`.

If you want to `remove` the `selection` every time your form is `load` you may set the **`SelectedIndex property`** of the control to **`-1.`**

[See forums](https://www.telerik.com/forums/radlistcontrol-seems-to-select-the-first-item-when-a-filter-is-applied)